# Why the output is not 0,1.Why it is 0,2.?

Tags: c, function-pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>
void f(int *p, int *q)
{
    p = q;
   *p = 2;
}
    int i = 0, j = 1;
int main()
{
    f(&i, &j);
    printf("%d %d \n", i, j);
    getchar();
return 0;
}
```

This code prints 0,2,why it does'nt print 0,1 because after *p=2 the value of j is assigned 1 right?can anyone help me

Comment: Because after `p = q;`, `p` points to `j`

Comment: but int  j=1; comes after *p=2; right ,why value doesnt change there to 1

Comment: It may be off-topic: but i suggest for simpler code examples like this one, taking a pen & a paper and re-drawing what happens may help u understand. Also: i suggest reading not the standard, but tutorials may help spark your interest and help understanding.

I can suggest - besides others - https://www.learncpp.com/ . it's easy to understand and also copes with pointers.

Comment: @Akshay Hebbar If you are assigning 2  (  *p = 2; ) why the result must be equal to 1?!!!

Comment: @AkshayHebbar Feel free to accept an answer of ours if your problem has been solved.

Answer (score 1):

Inside `f` you are assigning the pointer `p` the **pointer** value of `q`.

Means - after `p = q;`, both `p` and `q` point to the same int which is `j`.

That's why you get 0,2.

Answer (score 0):

**"after `*p=2` the value of `j` is assigned `1` right?"**

No, function `f()` ends at the closing `}` brace, and
`j` was assigned the value of `1` before `main()` begins.

The line

```
int i = 0, j = 1;
```

could equally well be further up, before function `f()`.

Comment: Okay!! Function ends after closing the bracket ‘}’ , but why i=0; then ?

Comment: I don't understand you. `i` is initialised as `0` and is printed as `0` too. It has not been modifed or used in the program, and only you know why it is in the code at all.

Answer (score 0):

> "because after `*p = 2;` the value of `j` is assigned by `1` right?"

No. You seem to confuse here something very hard in terms of control flow and scope. The definition of `f` is placed before the definitions of the global variables `i` and `j`.

That doesn't mean that the global variables get assigned after the function.

```
int i = 0, j = 1;
```

are definitions of `i` and `j` (declaration with immediate initializations) at global scope, not assignments.

The value of `j` `2` after the call to `f` is correct because:

- 1. `j` is passed by reference to `f` and its address is assigned to the pointer parameter `q`.
- 2. The value of the pointer `q` is assigned to the pointer `p`.
- 3. `p` is dereferenced then which points to `j` in the caller and assigns `2` to `j`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what happens:

```
statement                  i   j   p   q
-----------------------------------------
int i = 0, j = 1;          0   1   -   -
f(&i, &j);                 0   1   &i  &j
p = q;                     0   1   &j  &j
*p = 2;                    0   2   &j  &j
printf("%d %d \n", i, j);  0   2   -   -
```